# Solution of boundary value problem using Fourier series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, boundary-value-problem

I want to solve the following PDE using Fourier series:

- $u(x,y): \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$,
- $\Omega=(0,\pi)\times (0,2\pi)$
- $u-3u_{xx}-u_{yy}= 3\sin(2x)-\sin(5x)$

$u_{xx}$ and $u_{yy}$ are second derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ respectively. The boundary conditions of the problem are:

- Dirichlet boundary condition in $x$ direction: $u(x=0,y)=u(x=\pi,y)=0$
- Neumann boundary condition in $y$ direction: $u_y(x,y=0)=u_y(x,y=2\pi)=0$

I chose my base functions for $u$ such that they satisfy boundary conditions: $\sin(nx)\cos(my/2)$. Therefore, the left-hand side of the equation would be: $$\sum a(n,m)\left[1+3n^2+\frac{m^2}{4}\right]\sin(nx)\cos(my/2)$$
My problem is that I should be able to write the right-hand side of the equation in form of $\sum b(n,m)\sin(nx)\cos(my/2)$, so that I can obtain $a(n,m)$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit the question, instead of using * to bold the text, use \$ text \$. For example: \$\pi\$ renders as $\pi$.

Comment: See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for info on how to typeset math formulas using mathjax/latex. It's really easy to learn.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and also the edit.

Comment: $m=0$ is allowed, which means $\sin(2x),\sin(5x) \in \{ \sin(nx)\cos(my) : 1 \le n < \infty, \;\; 0 \le m <\infty \}$

Answer (score 1):

You have to project the left-hand and right-hand sides of the PDE on the basis $\sin(nx)\cos(my/2)$, that is you have to compute
$$\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi} \Bigl(\sum_{n,m}a(n,m)[1+3n^2+m^2/4]\sin(nx)\cos(my/2)-3\sin(2x)+\sin(5x)\Bigr)\sin(nx)\cos(my/2)\, \mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x,\quad \forall n,m$$
It will give you the missing terms so that you can solve in $a(n,m)$.